# "await is a reserved word" when converting a promise to an await call

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have the following code that works ok:

```
// api.js
export default {
    async readAsync (resource) {
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 400));
        return data[resource];
    },
}

// ProductList.vue
import api from '@/services/api'

[...]

  methods: {
    fetch () {
      this.loading = true;
      api.readAsync('products').then(data => {
        this.products = data;
        this.loading = false;
      });
    }
  }

[...]
```

I want to use await to get rid of the promise, like this:

```
  methods: {
    fetch () {
      this.loading = true;
      this.products = await api.readAsync('products');;
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }
```

But I get the following error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): 
SyntaxError: D:\devel\apps\vue-tests\cli-test\src\components\ProductList.vue: await is a reserved word (59:22)
  57 | this.loading = true;
  58 | 
> 59 | this.products = await api.readAsync('products');; 
     |                 ^ 
  60 | this.loading = false;
```

Any idea what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I saw the duplicate answer before asking, and now I realize that indeed is the correct answer, nevertheless the example given and the explanation seems more difficult to follow, I think this answer is far more clear and easy to follow.

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare your `fetch` method as `async` in order to use the `await` keyword:

```
async fetch () {
  this.loading = true;
  this.products = await api.readAsync('products');;
  this.loading = false;
}
```

Comment: May be you could make it better with a `try catch` block